# Sending a scalar by refrence between -=IF ELSE=- Statments in perl

Tags: perl

Is it possible to make a scalar live between =-if(){}else{}=- statement?

Code example:

```
if ($packet =~
   /(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)(\.?(\d{2,5})?) (>) (\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)(\.?(\d{2,5})?(.*))/ ) {
   ($srcip, $srcport, $icmp, undef, $dstip, $dstport) =
      ($1,  $PORTS->("$3"), $2, $4, $5, $PORTS->("$7"));
   my $proto = $8;
   $proto_ref = \$proto;
 } else {
   my @IP = split(/\s+/, $packet);
   if ($IP[10] =~ s/(\.?)(\d{2,6}$|\w{2,6})$//g) {
     $srcip = $IP[10];
     $srcport = $PORTS->("$2");
   }

   if ($IP[12] =~ s/(\.?)(\d{2,6}$|\w{2,6})$//g) {
     $dstip = $IP[12];
     $dstport = $PORTS->("$2");
   }
 }
```

I want `$proto = $8` to be a general scalar to the end of the script !. 
Thanks

Comment: first regex whill not properly valid ip address and ports., for example it will be match monsters like [this](http://regexr.com/38ml1)

Comment: Your questions sounds as if you wanted to solve some underlying problem... Why do you not put the `my $proto;` before the `if`? If you do not want it to contain any meaningful value in the else case, you could `undef $proto` it there.

Comment: You shouldn't put your variables in quotes. `$PORTS->($3)` etc. is correct. And why don't you take the parentheses off in `(>)`? Then you could remove the `undef` in the assignment list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to accomplish? 
The core problem you've got is to do with perl scoping rules - a variable declared with `my` only exists within the code block it's declared within. The contents of the variable may persist longer if you create a reference to it, but that reference still has the same scoping rules.

So the 'proper' answer is: declare `my $proto` outside your `if` code blocks, and put those references down.

Answer (score 0):

Why not scope `$proto` outside of your `if` clause. Then it will persist until the end of its new expanded scope, eg:

```
my $proto;
if ($packet =~/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)(\.?(\d{2,5})?) (>) (\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)(\.?(\d{2,5})?(.*))/ ) {
    ($srcip, $srcport, $icmp, undef, $dstip, $dstport) =
      ($1,  $PORTS->("$3"), $2, $4, $5, $PORTS->("$7"));
    $proto = $8;
} else {
    my @IP = split(/\s+/, $packet);
    if ($IP[10] =~ s/(\.?)(\d{2,6}$|\w{2,6})$//g) {
        $srcip = $IP[10];
        $srcport = $PORTS->("$2");
    }
}
```

A scalar persists as long as its in scope, or something that is still in scope is holding a reference to it.

Comment: I failed to clarify my problem, however i managed to solve it. Thanks again